# Accessing docker network from npm script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, npm, amazon-dynamodb, docker-network

I have a simple npm script that creates a local Dynamo DB table, the Dynamo DB is running in it's own docker network called `lambda-local`. The purpose of having it run in it's own Docker network is to allow it to communicate with the local development environment when running `sam local start-api --docker-network lambda-local`

But where this strategy fails is when I try to create a table using the npm script since it cannot see Dynamo DB which is running in a Docker container, although it works if I just run Dynamo DB on localhost...
Any way to give some kind of access to the script to the Docker network on runtime? It is a Javascript file...
Question comes from Docker rookie, I couldn't figure out this myself so had to shout for help, any comment is appreciated even if it's stating that what I am trying to achieve is impossible

Comment: Could you run the npm script within a container, and start that container with the `--network` option to join the lambda-local network? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings Alternately, does the dynamodb instance have a published port?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do currently using this Dockerfile:```FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
ADD scripts ./

RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm", "run", "create-table" ]``` But all I get is ```Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/scripts/create_table.js'```

Comment: Does that file exist inside the container? Log into the container with `docker run -it <container name> bash` and run `ls /usr/src/app/scripts/create_projektt_table.js` inside the container.

Comment: Worked if used like ```ADD scripts scripts/```

Comment: Makes sense. By the way, you should prefer COPY over ADD if you're not trying to download a URL or unpack a tarball: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-2-the-difference-between-copy-and-add-in-a-dockerile